# CakePHP saveMany meets foreign key constrain failed error?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys

I try to $this->MembersQuestionsAnswer->saveMany($data).

And $data is this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'member_id' => '4',
        'questions_anwser_id' => '102'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'member_id' => '4',
        'questions_anwser_id' => '203'
    )
)
```

then I got error

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`dating_sys`.`members_questions_answers`, CONSTRAINT
>   `members_questions_answers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`questions_answer_id`)
>   REFERENCES `questions_answers` (`id`))
>
> SQL Query: INSERT INTO `dating_sys`.`members_questions_answers`
>   (`member_id`, `modified`) VALUES (4, '2012-11-14 01:13:27')

I checked the database. Both 102 and 203 do exist in table questions_answers id field. And I can also manually insert them into the table. Foreign key constraints work as I checked as well.

And the table members_questions_answers table DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE `members_questions_answers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `questions_answer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `member_fk` (`member_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `questions_answer_fk` (`questions_answer_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `members_questions_answers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`questions_answer_id`) REFERENCES `questions_answers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `members_questions_answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

It feels like questions_answers table not really identified for some reason. I did have changed the name of this table and its foreign keys references. Is there a cache or something?

Can anyone help or point me to a new way to look into?

Comment: Is the model set to use the Tree Behavior?

Comment: I found the problem. I misspelled 'answer' in the $data array to 'anwser'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like a caching issue. Clear your model cache files in app/tmp/cache/models (or whatever cache engine you are using)

Comment: I found the problem. I misspelled 'answer' in the $data array to 'anwser'.